# Good way on creating C# validation class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, validation, error-handling

I have a functionality that upload a file, validate it, save it to database and so on.

All of these actions are on some different classes and methods. But, if something goes wrong in any of these methods, I want to inform these errors to my front-end.

Is there a good way to manage this, let's call, "Error Class"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that you could take would be to create the "Error Class" like a service in your application and post the different classes and methods that perform various actions could post errors to it.

Now your front-end can either subscribe with the "Error Class" to know of errors immediately or you could return an error code the details of which can be found using the "Error Class"

Comment: If I create this Error Class, let's say that some validation error occurs in upload process, and this upload process keep going to other methods. And, let's say that on these others methods, some other validation errors occur, will I be able to add all these validation errors to this "Error Class"? This "Error Class" should be able to be instantiated from anywhere and I should be able to get this object from anywhere and filled with errors too.

Comment: This can be achieved by using a Dependency Injection Container like Unity or MEF, or you can make the Error Class 'Singleton'. Using either of the two approaches you can get hold of the "Error Class" in any of the classes and add the validation errors

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using StructureMap to handle DI. I was starting on creating this Error Class as static... Was I on the right way? I was thinking also in Singleton, but I don't know if this was suitable on this case...

Comment: I choose Singleton over Static to be able to mock out the class in Unit Test Cases. If that is not a problem for you than you can make the Error Class static. Otherwise I would say you should register an instance with the container and access it in the different classes

Comment: Hmm.. I will choose Singleton! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well lets say, your sequence of processing a file is

1. Upload
2. Validate
3. Save
4. Return with success result/error.

Now, in all these sequence if its same all the time, then you could just go for exception throwing mechanism and collect it at the front end. May be you could throw with an Error ID.